# Minimal setup for a secured microservice environment

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, single-sign-on, api-gateway

I would like to setup an SSO microservice environment with Gradle, Spring Boot2, Zuul, JWT, Microservices with a REST-Api and a self made Authentication server.
What are the Annotations for the Authentication Server, the Gateway and the Microservices when they act as OAuth clients and as Resource Servers? What is the minimal setup?

Answer (score 5):

for the gradle config I suggest to use the web site http://start.spring.io/ and for the authorization server. the configuration will be like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

then the auth server will be like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class SecurityOAuth2AutorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AccountUserDetailsService accountUserDetailsService;
    private final UserDetailsService authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityOAuth2AutorizationServerConfig(UserDetailsService accountUserDetailsService,
                                                  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.accountUserDetailsService = accountUserDetailsService;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.approvalStoreDisabled()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .userDetailsService(accountUserDetailsService)
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid")
                .authorities("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_EMPLOYEE")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust", "openid")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60*60*8);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        ....
    }
}
```

the configuration of login page for the sso will be like:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService accountUserDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(new User("user", "secret",
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"))));

        return inMemoryUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

In your application in sso you can have a configuration like below:

```
 @EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class SsoDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsoDemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext context,
                                                 OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails authorizationCodeResourceDetails) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(authorizationCodeResourceDetails, context);
    }

}
```

in your application.yml:

```
 security:
      oauth2:
        client:
         clientId: client
         clientSecret: secret
         accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9090/auth/oauth/token
         userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9090/auth/oauth/authorize
         auto-approve-scopes: '.*'
         registered-redirect-uri: http://localhost:9090/auth/singin
         clientAuthenticationScheme: form
        resource:
          jwt:
            key-value: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
      ......
                       -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

server:
  use-forward-headers: true

zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  ignoreSecurityHeaders: false
  addHostHeader: true
  routes:
    your-service: /your-service/**

proxy:
  auth:
    routes:
      spent-budget-service: oauth2
```

in this way you configure the your client application in sso with your auth server the @EnableOAuth2Sso will do anythings for you it is also like a client application and if your app is not authenticated your sso will redirect you on the login page of your auth server and will refresh your token for you zuul token relay it is also available as feature in this use case I use eureka as discovery service registry. It is very important configure the OAuth2RestTemplate because spring will use this bean for refresh your token automatically for you otherwise as soon as your token expires you will do not able to automatically refresh teh token.

all your resourceserver will be like this:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccountServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

in your application.yml:

```
 security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwt:
        key-value: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
   .....
                   -----END PUBLIC KEY----
```

-

of course it is very minimal configuration but id enough just for start

**UPDATE:**

do not forget the resource configuration in application yml on your gateway, sso and any other resource server because otherwise it will impossible to validate the token against your auth server.

In case of a plain oauth2 token you can use the

```
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri: your/auth/server:yourport/oauth/check_token
```

or

```
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri: yourAccountDEtailsRndpoint/userInfo.json
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo: false
```

your typical account data entpoint on auth server in case of preferTokenInfo: false.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
class UserRestFullEndPoint {

    @GetMapping("/userInfo")
    public Principal userInfo(Principal principal){
        return principal;
    }
}
```

UserInfoRestTemplateFactory in case of token-info-uri configuration will be provided automaticaty by spring the only thing to remember is configure the Oauth2RestTemplate because otherwise your token will not refreshed any more

**UPDATE 2**

In case of a non JWT token the missing configuration is to add 
a @EnableResourceServer on your auth server.

In this way your user info uri will return the principal object like a json for instance. The problem hear was that your endpoint will return in any case null and therefore your service received a 401. It happen because your auth server is able only to return token and not to able to expose other service that are not framework endpoint in order to provide token. Since that you need to return user info, you need of a way to expose resource and therefore you need to expose out auth server even like a resource server. In case of jwt it is useless because the token verification and user info will be provided by token itself. The user info will be provided by the jwt and the verification by jwt key.

**resume your auth server will be like below:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class UserInfo {

    @GetMapping("/account/user-info")
    public Principal principal(Principal principal){
        System.out.println(principal);
        return principal;
    }

}

@Controller
class Login{

    @GetMapping(value = "/login", produces = "application/json")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
class SecurityOAuth2AutorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .approvalStoreDisabled()
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                .userDetailsService(accountUserDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService accountUserDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(new User("user", passwordEncoder.encode("secret"),
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"))));

        return inMemoryUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_EMPLOYEE")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust", "openid")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(20000000)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(20000000);
    }

}

@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/account/userInfo", "/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

login page:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap-theme.css}"/>

    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form role="form" action="login" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.js}" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
  port: 9090
  servlet:
    context-path: /auth


management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"

spring:
  application:
    name: authentication-server
```

**your sso server wil be like below:**

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class SsoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext context,
                                                 OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails authorizationCodeResourceDetails) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(authorizationCodeResourceDetails, context);
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

simple page on http://localhost:8080/index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

It Works by an SSO

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "/hello-service/hello",
        success: function (data, status) {
            window.alert("The returned data" + data);
        }
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
     clientId: client
     clientSecret: secret
     accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9090/auth/oauth/token
     userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9090/auth/oauth/authorize
     auto-approve-scopes: '.*'
     registered-redirect-uri: http://localhost:9090/auth/login
     clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9090/auth/account/user-info
      prefer-token-info: false


management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
  port: 8080

zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  ignoreSecurityHeaders: false
  addHostHeader: true
  routes:
    hello-service:
      serviceId: hello-service
      path: /hello-service/**
      url: http://localhost:4040/

proxy:
  auth:
    routes:
      hello-service: oauth2
```

**your hello service (resourceserver) will be :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ResourceServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class HelloService {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public ResponseEntity hello(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World!!!");
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class SecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

I hope that it can be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick answer. I have a problem making it work. Perhaps you have another good idea. 
I`m not authorized to access my resource on 'http://localhost:9977/service/home'.
**My server and Zuul code:**

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class StackServerApplication {

    @GetMapping("/oauth/check_token")
    public java.security.Principal userInfo(Principal principal){
        return principal;
    }

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate userInfoRestTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext context,
            OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails authorizationCodeResourceDetails) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(authorizationCodeResourceDetails, context);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserInfoRestTemplateFactory userInfoRestTemplateFactory() {
        return new UserInfoRestTemplateFactory() {

            @Override
            public OAuth2RestTemplate getUserInfoRestTemplate() {
                return userInfoRestTemplate;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
     clientId: client
     clientSecret: secret
     accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9977/auth/oauth/token
     userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9977/auth/oauth/authorize
     auto-approve-scopes: '.*'
     registered-redirect-uri: http://localhost:9977/auth/singin
     clientAuthenticationScheme: form
     resource:
       token-info-uri: http://localhost:9977/oauth/check_token  
       preferTokenInfo: false  

server:
  use-forward-headers: true
  port: 9977

zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  ignoreSecurityHeaders: false
  addHostHeader: true
  routes:
    service:
      url: http://localhost:8080

proxy:
  auth:
    routes:
      service: oauth2
```

**Resource Server:**

```
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackResourceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackResourceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    public class ServiceController {

        @GetMapping("/home")
        public String home() {
            return "Hermie";
        }            
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:9977/oauth/check_token  
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

When I call 'http://localhost:9977/service/home', server tells me that I'm not authorized.

Comment: seeing your code I see that yon do not use a jwt token otherwise I expect a security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value valorized tag. In any case even in a plain oauth2 token is mandatory configure the  security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri: your/auth/server:yourport/oauth/check_token in gateway and in any resourceserver because otherwise the sso and resourceserver can not validate your token

Comment: anyway I had update my answer in order to try to explain how overcome the your problems

Comment: Yes, I deleted the jwt token, to make it easier. In my 'StackServerApplication' I added a oauth/check_token Rest Endpoint and in the yml files the 'resource' tags, but I'm still unauthorized while accessing 'http://localhost:9977/service/home'.

Comment: you have delete UserInfoRestTemplateFactory and @GetMapping("/oauth/check_token") on your auth server should be mapped in on another path because this path is already implemented by a @FrameworkEndpoint it is better do not touch internal spring components

Comment: however I m preparing a very small poc and I will publish hear on git hub in this way I can send you a compelte example I suppose that via messages we are not understan each other some details

Comment: I appreciate your kind support, thank you very much.

Comment: I updated my answer and pushed on my github the my solution

Comment: https://github.com/mrFlick72/oauth2-demo/tree/master it is the link of my solution